# can not access index.html page through MAMP

Tags: php, html, localhost, mamp

I am studying fundamentals of PHP programming and during my first program I encountered some problems with MAMP.I created a "first" directoory with index.html file inside the htdoccs directory.But i can not access this file through MAMP localhost.What is the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyv15.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giwIS.jpg)

Comment: Having an `index.php` *and* an `index.html` file doesn't really make sense. What's the index.html for in your case? You should treat the index.php file as your starting/home page.

Answer (score 0):

The first folder has an uppercase F, `First` have you tried renaming it to `first` or using `First` in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

For MAMP, a web page **starts** from htdocs,

So instead of

```
http://localhost/MAMP/first/index.html
```

please visit

```
http://localhost/First/index.html
```

For windows environment, letter case may not be the problem, so First, first , FIRst are all "ok", but if you migrate the code to a unix/linux platform, letter case **must** matches. Hence as a good practice please make sure you use the letter case in links properly